# how to have navbar background appear when the toggle button is active

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The way I have my navbar set up right now is when I am scrolled to the top, the navbar background is transparent, and as soon as I start scrolling down, the navbar background appears as black. The only problem I am having right now is when I am on mobile size and I am scrolled to the top, when I click the navbar toggle dropdown button, the background on the drop down menu is transparents since I am scrolled all the way up, but I'd like to find a way to have the black background appear when the dropdown menu is active when scrolled all the way to the top of the browser.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default top-of-page">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/fv-logo-3.gif' align="left"/></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul id="navLinks" class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="http://www.floridavisions.com">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="/stock">Stock Photography/ Footage</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Java Script

```
<script>  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPos <= 0) {
        $('.navbar-default').addClass('top-of-page');
    } else {
        $('.navbar-default').removeClass('top-of-page');
    }
});
   </script>
```

CSS

```
.top-of-page {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
.navbar-default {
        background-color: black;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.85);
        min-height: 90px;
        position: fixed;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: none;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1; 
    } 
    #navLinks {
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    #navLinks li {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
    #navLinks li a {
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    #navLinks li a:hover {
        color: #a6b1c4;
    }
    .navbar-brand img {
        height: 35px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Write media query. when device width is less than something say 700px for phone give background color to ... top-of-page class. 
code ...

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.top-of-page{
   background-color: #000;
}
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that the black background would appear when the dropdown menu was not active.

Comment: then also check for non active class.  and add css to that